# Can I use aluminum foil as a substitute for parchment paper?

Tags: baking

I'm attempting to make this recipe for [Greek Meatza](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/greek-meatza-with-creamy-feta-kalamata-olives-and-red-onion/) which calls for baking ground beef in a pan on top of parchment paper.

I don't have access to parchment paper, so I'm wondering: can I substitute aluminum foil? If so, are there any adjustments I should make to the time or temperature for baking?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that aluminum foil would have a very different "heating profile" (I'm not sure that's a real term) than parchment paper and probably wouldn't make a good substitute.

Comment: You should also realize that aluminum foil has unsavory chemical reactions when it gets in contact with tomato sauces... thus when I rub meat with a tomato paste before cooking, I put a layer of parchment paper between the foil and the meat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you're making. The principal differences are:

- Parchment is much more non-stick than aluminum foil. I haven't tried non-stick aluminum myself, so no idea how that compares.
- Parchment insulates (against heat transfer) more than aluminum.
- Parchment is somewhat porous; it absorbs water.

Looking at that recipe quickly, it'd probably work fine. I'd suggest substituting aluminum foil sprayed with Pam (non-stick cooking spray). The bottom may brown a little quicker with the foil.

Answer (score 2):

I've never made Meatza, but making a naive assumption that it's comparable to meatloaf (with toppings), I actually have better success w/ the non-stick reynolds wrap then i do w/ parchment paper... @uncle Brad's point is really valid and to that point, I've never had a problem w/ the aluminum foil changing the temp profile...

But again, I havent actually done what you're asking w/ that dish...